# Why shouldn't I change the owner on /etc/hosts to myself?

Tags: macos, terminal

Basically, I want to block a bunch of websites and I don't want to use a browser plugin to do it, so I am using an `alias` to overwrite `/etc/hosts` with a list of domains that re-direct to 0.0.0.0. When I need to be able to view these sites again, I use another `alias` to overwrite the file again with the original file

Except it's annoying to be asked to enter my password all the time whenever the file is overwritten, so I changed the owner of the file from root to my user.

Any real issue with this?

Answer (score 1):

Two things...

1. Don't use 0.0.0.0 - that won't always do what you expect. It's shorthand for 'use the default path' not 'redirect to local'. Use 127.0.0.1 instead.
2. Rather than mess with permissions - whilst not particularly dangerous, makes your setup non-standard & who knows how standards may change in future & catch you unawares - why not try [Gas Mask](http://clockwise.ee) (freeware, no affiliation) which not only eliminates the need to change the perms, but also allows you multiple versions of the hosts file, switchable on the fly.

[image]

To use, Create a new file - it will setup the defaults automatically. Copy/paste any existing setup you want to carry over from any file to any other. Add any new data in the same format - it's very lenient on formatting, tab or space.
Save, then activate.
You can swap profiles any time the app is running, otherwise your last chosen will persist.
Activating a profile makes it immediately available.
 <sub>Note: the use of 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost for IPV6 is non-standard, but just seems to make the Mac behave better</sub>

Comment: ooh, shiny. Yeah, that seems nice

Answer (score 0):

While not a best practice, if its just you using the system, and if you are not running any services as your user it should be OK.

Another solutionight be to use sudo when running the scripts, and set it up so those activities don't require a password.

Comment: How do I do the latter part of your suggestion

Comment: `sudo alias` and however you want. Basically prefixing alias with sudo. It will prompt you for your password (or your root password - depends on your set up)

Comment: @Darius - sorry, but thats not quite right.  sudo does not prompt you for the root password (su does).  sudo can be configured to ask for a password or to simply do what its asked without a password depending on whats configured in /etc/sudoers (use visudo to edit this file) and sometimes /etc/sudoers.d - if you use the parameter NOPASSWD: ALL in this file you can supress password prompts.

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the clarification. I have been used to system where the /etc/sudoers have `Defaults rootpw` hence why I said it depends on your setup.